# Possible to combine/concatenate MD5 hashes?

Tags: hash, md5, sha1, sha256, crc32

For CRC32, it is possible to combine two hashes, such that given two streams A and B, we can find out CRC(A+B) knowing only CRC(A), CRC(B), and length(B). *(Implementation available [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c#L372), along with an explanation for how this works by Mark Adler [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/SHyr5bp5rtc)).*

This allows us, for example, to compute a hash on a single stream in parallel, or to compute a hash on a large *(as in 'doesn't fit in memory')*, severely fragmented stream using only forward seeking on its containing medium *(this offers enormous potential for speedup on very slow media)*.

There don't appear to be implementations for such behavior available for other, more complex, hashing algorithms like MD5. Is this behavior fundamentally impossible with MD5? Is it just so difficult to do that no one bothered trying yet? What about more complex algorithms like SHA1 or SHA256? I would love to hear any insights on this.

Comment: Streaming hashing is pretty common; here’s a PHP example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php . However, these algorithms may require more context during streaming than just `md5(A)`, `md5(B)`, and `length(B)`.

Comment: I'm actually asking something different than streaming hashing. I'm aware that I can do Init(), Update(A), Update(B), Z=Finalize(). I'm trying to do Init(), Update(A), X=Finalize(), Init(), Update(B), Y=Finalize(), Z=Combine(X,Y). It's possible with CRC32 but I get a feeling that with any more complex popular hash algorithms I'm out of luck.

Comment: MD5, SHA1, and every other *cryptographic* hash function I'm aware do not have the algebraic properties that CRC has. Any such properties would represent a devastating weakness in the crypt context. In particular, none of them can be computed in parallel on separate chunks like a CRC can.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *should* not be possible for any cryptographic hash. If it were possible, then that hash could no longer be considered cryptographic.